# In $\triangle ABC$, with $D$ on $BC$, if perpendiculars from $D$ to the other sides are equal, can we conclude that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles?

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the figure, $\triangle ABC$ is a triangle. There exists a point $D$ on $BC$ such that when two perpendicular lines are drawn from $D$ to $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, $DE = DF$, where $E$ and $F$ are the intersection points. Must it be true that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles?

It should be obvious to prove that $\square AEDF$ is a kite, with $AE = AF$ and $DE=DF$. However, how can we draw any conclusion about $\triangle ABC$? Any help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: You're correct about the kite. Now consider: Is there anything about the situation that guarantees the kite is balancing perfectly "upright"?

Comment: @Blue : How about rotating BC while fixing point D? Then I may not obtain an isosceles triangle?

Comment: Exactly. :) ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join AD. Let angle $ADE = \alpha$ and angle $ADF = \beta$ then

$DE \sec{\alpha} =DF \sec{\beta} = AD$

(They both are equal to AD)

As $ DE = DF $, thus $\alpha = \beta$

Now $AD\sin{\alpha} = AD\sin{beta}$
Thus $AE = AF$

Now we can see from above derived conditions that $\Delta ABD$ is congruent with $\Delta ACD$. Also that AD must be angle bisector of and at A.

But these conditions only fix A ,E, D and F (that they must form a cyclic quadrilateral). It doesn't tell anything about points B & C, not the queue at them.

To make it more intuitive, you can imagine that if we increase side AB a bit and reduce side AC a bit such that B, D and C remain collinear without disturbing AEFD ,triangle wouldn't be isosceles.

You can also use co-ordinate geometry to check further

Comment: Please check the congruent triangles.

Answer (score 1):

All we can say is that $E$ and $F$ are points of a circle with center $D$, and $BC$ is on a line that passes thorough $D$.[image]